# AWS batch to execute on prem batch code through a rest call or via sending event

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch, autosys

Can I trigger on premises batch from AWS without migrating batch code.
is it possible through rest call or queue?

I don't want to move batch code to AWS instead just call batch code from AWS

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why a service running in AWS would not be able to call your on-premise service provided one of these things are true:

1. Your service is accessible the entire internet
2. Your on-premises firewalls allow inbound connections from the the [AWS IP address ranges](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/aws-ip-ranges.html) of interest
3. You have set up [VPN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/index.html) routing between your on-premise network and your AWS resources

For all of these your service should use authentication for the requests.